# Action icon in the bottom right of Custom VF Page in SF1

Tags: salesforce1-app, global-actions

I'm trying to get the Action / + icon to show up in SF1 Custom VF pages. I have tried adding "Global Actions", object specific actions and using the Standard Controller on the Custom VF Page, all to no avail.

I have also tried digging around in the sforce.one and canvas.publisher js api's to no avail.

I feel like the answer to popping the action lightbox (the result of the + click) lies in the canvas.publisher js api, but I can't seem to find it. This would not be as nice of a solution as simply dropping the standard Action icon on top of the page, but could work.

[image: Chatter action icon in sf1 custom vf]

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell / ascertain - there currently is no supported way to do make the Action / + button appear on a VF page, be it app, global action or record action in S1 Mobile.  The screenshot was probably taken back while Salesforce1 was still in beta and overlaying that might have been default then.  There are lots of reasons not to do that, mostly the potential conflict that such JS injection might incur from either a code or UI perspective.

It's possible it might return as a publisher.js method at some point.

Comment: From my perspective it would be fine to have a parameter in the header of the VF page to include the Action / + icon in the SF1 rendering of the page. Even a sforce.one.showActionIconForObject(); or sforce.one.showGlobalActionIcon() method would work for me. Hopefully that would be able to communicate back to the app to avoid any security/injection issues, and show the appropriate icon.